# How to group rows based on values from another column in dataprep?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, alteryx, google-cloud-dataprep, trifacta, dataprep

I'm new to Dataprep and I'm struggling to write basic formulas and conditions.

In the image below you can see what I'm trying to do.
[DataPrep screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdEf9.png)

I have 'PROJETO' Column, 'PEP' Column and 'QUANTIDADE' Column. I want to sum 'QUANTIDADE' values that match conditions in PEP column.

Example:

```
| PROJETO | PEP | QUANTIDADE |
| -------- | -------------- |--------|
| E.ADBR001 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.IS.XPTO|1|
| E.ADBR001 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.IS.XPTO|2|
| E.ADBR001 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.IS.XPTO|3|
| E.ADBR008 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.IS.XPTO|4|
| E.ADBR008 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.IS.XPTO|5|
| E.ADBR008 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.IS.XPTO|6|
| E.ADBR001 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.AT.XPTO|10|
| E.ADBR001 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.AT.XPTO|20|
| E.ADBR001 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.AT.XPTO|30|
| E.ADBR008 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.AT.XPTO|40|
| E.ADBR008 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.AT.XPTO|50|
| E.ADBR008 |E.ADBR001.L2.EN.AT.XPTO|60|
```

In the case of

```
`PEP LIKE {PROJETO}{any character}EN.IS{any character}`
```

i would like to sum quantidade column and group in a PROJETO row (whatever in a new table or column), like this:

| PROJETO | EN.IS | EN.AT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| E.ADBR001 | 6 (3+2+1) | 60 (30+20+10) |
| E.ADBR008 | 15 (6+5+4) | 150 (60+50+40) |

I tried something like

```
`SUMIF(QUANTIDADE, PEP='%*EN.IS%*')`
```

in "Values" in "Group By" action from Dataprep. I really dont know if the use of %*, as I read on documentation, indicate any character in a string, and I'm really struggling to manipulate strings.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This is tagged with Alteryx. I don't know anything about Trifecta Dataprep but if you have Alteryx this is fairly trivial with their Summarize tool: https://help.alteryx.com/current/en/designer/tools/transform/summarize-tool.html#summarize-tool